# 100% Height Div with Margin or Padding Scrollbar Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble eliminating the vertical scrollbar when applying a 50px padding (black) to the .background style.

```
html, body {height:100%; margin: 0; padding:0;}

div.background
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px;
}

div.transbox
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

div.transbox p
{
  margin: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

This is what it looks like

http://jsfiddle.net/sm6LLgp4/2/

If I remove the top and bottom padding (black), the scrollbars are gone, but I've also lost my padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/sm6LLgp4/3/

How can I maintain the 50px padding all around without the vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert **box-sizing:border:box**, than it works.

```
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```